# Seeking advice with dissertation chair: possible theft of idea and possible blackmail

Tags: thesis, advisor, ethics, plagiarism

I am hoping for advice in how to move forward. Last spring I submitted two proposal ideas to my dissertation chair. He told me that the first idea was 'inappropriate.' I proposed a comparison of statistical methods, and my advisor said that I could not compare the 'new and novel' method to the 'traditional' analysis method. He felt that it was inappropriate to make a comparison between these methods. Before telling me that I could not continue with this idea, he asked me to type up notes about each statistical procedure (background, assumptions, how to complete, coding packages, etc.) as well as to send him the relevant literature supporting the 'new' methods. I sent him approximately 28 pages of typed notes discussing each method in depth and my entire file of literature sources. Then, he told me that I could not move forward with this idea.

So, I selected a new topic. One semester later, my advisor sent me a draft paper that he was submitting to a conference. He told me that if I completed the statistical analysis, I could be the fourth author on the paper. I was shocked to read that paper, as it was my original dissertation idea of comparing methods. I refused to work on the paper. I attempted to discuss my concern that the paper was very close to my original dissertation proposal; while my chair says that I 'motivated' him to explore a new area of research, he denies that he is using my idea.

Now, I believe that my chair is holding up my dissertation. I was supposed to defend my proposal in July, but he has refused to allow me to schedule the defense. This summer, he told me that I was ready to defend, that my proposal was solid, and that my first three chapters were in good shape. However, he thought a fall meeting date would benefit the faculty committee members. In the meantime, he instructed me to begin conducting the proposed research in anticipation of committee approval in the fall.

This semester, I have had two meetings with my chair. In both meetings, he has brought up that he wants me to perform the statistical analysis of his new project (which I believe to be my original dissertation proposal). He even suggested that I should extend my studies for an additional year and apply to be his research assistant. I have not agreed to participate in the research project or to delay my graduation. After telling him that I would not participate in the research project, he sent me an email questioning if my proposed dissertation (representing three semesters of work) was sufficient or if I should start again with a new topic.

So....
I have reached out to the omsbud office and I have debated filing an ethics complaint against my chair. I also reached out to the program coordinator of my program to request a change in dissertation chair. To change chairs, I may be required to file a complaint because I am in my third semester of dissertation hours.

I am hoping for advice. I worry about repercussions if I file a complaint. A student filed a complaint against this particular professor two years ago and that student was ostracised by both faculty and her peers. She dropped out of the program. This summer, I thought that the best course of action was to keep my head down, ignore my concerns, and finish my dissertation. Now, I wonder if I will be able to finish my dissertation as my chair will not allow me to schedule the proposal defense. I am further restricted from contacting any members of my committee; one of the covid policies that my department adopted was that all communication must go through the committee chair. So, I have five members on my committee, but I am only allowed to communicate directly with the chair. I tell you, I would not believe this story if I was not living it myself.

Currently, the path of least resistance seems to be quitting the program but then I forfeit all the time and work spent towards this degree.

Comment: Your post is very long. We would like to help, but is it possible to compress the story to get a clearer picture? Also,do you have an ombudsperson at your university?

Comment: It is crucial to find out if your university has a student complaints procedure. If it has, it is probably (or should be) independent of the people you are concerned about. This is the best place to seek advice and help within the university’s own published procedures. Keep a timed and dated record of all events, emails, conversations.

Comment: Thank you. Good suggestions. @Anton

Comment: "one of the covid policies that my department adopted was that all communication must go through the committee chair" Frankly, from my perspective this is just bizarre. COVID-19 is not a reason to restrict communication channels. Can you please add a location tag?

Comment: I downvoted because the question says you have already decided what to do.

Answer (score 0):

In my view, you did well. It is very courageous what you have done so far and science needs people like you.

The difference with the girl you refer to from two years ago is that probably she had not contacted the ombudsperson and you are second. I suspect there are more cases. Would be good for you if you discretely can find out as it may help your case.

It is difficult to predict the outcome in these situations but I believe on a higher level in life, you will succeed whether here or somewhere else. Shallow comfort: Your case will also add to the file of this supervisor.

You did not ask for this to happen but it did. It is not your fault. It may take you extra time but in the end it will enforce your personal strength.

You may consider to ask the ombudsperson to start an independent investigation. An ombudsperson can start such investigation if there is sufficient reason. In that case he/she should able to keep you out of shot and a formal complaint from you should not be necessary.

Take care, trust your instincts and do not let this unfortunate situation break down your self confidence.